# Make endless rings visual effect in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I would like to have a visual effect as follows in my Unity project. I want the circles to change color every second if possible.

[image]

Is there any way to have this without any additional library? If not, please, link your suggestion. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use particle effects:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byxivSC1xYM

This is how it worked at my end:
[image]

[Ring png I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrbxW.png)

Note: In the tutorial, the shader for the material was selected "Particles/Additive". It's deprecated. If you don't see that option, choose "Particles/Standard Surface", and Set the Rendering Mode under "Blending Options" "Additive".

[image: demonstration]

Answer (score 1):

If the size is constant, you can simply turn that image you already have into a black and white image (White rings and black/transparent background), and then change the color each second or so.

```
class Rings {
  void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(this.ChangeColor());
  }
  IEumerator ChangeColor() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = newColor;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to solve the problem programmatically?

Comment: In that case, you'll have to create your own 2D mesh. I am not very experienced with it either, but you can follow this link here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606756/creating-a-2d-circular-mesh-in-unity For full circles, have the triangles emit out from the center like a pizza slice. For the ring, you'll have to use trapezoids to simulate the ring shape